# orientDB vertex and edge relationships

Tags: orientdb

is there a way to specify relationships and limits between vertices in OrientDB (through java api or sql)?

For example, I have a vertex Person, Cat, Dog.
And I want to create an edge Loves that is limited to Person -> Loves -> Dog or Person -> Loves -> Cat. Is this possible without sub-typing Dog and Cat into some abstract Vertex?

Is there also a way to specify that edge Loves can either have a (in Person and out Cat) OR (in Cat and out Person)?

Excuse me if there is already a similar question but I couldn't find one. Any help/suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT**. I ended up using indexing as I've read somewhere to specify what 'out' and 'in' edges properties class types are - and that caused massive performance issues when adding many edges at a time. I decided to move that into a java method and manually check if the new edge is a valid edge.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution other than creating a parent class like `Pet` and restricting the `Loves` edge to that?

Comment: Kimberly W - no, I haven't, so I just had to wrap them in a class.